# Cannot edit table cell: Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, javabeans, tablecelleditor

I created a custom table using BeanTableModel as tableModel (not sure if this matters). The table populates data from an enum Object, and shoudl write to the object as well. Currently the behavior is that the table will populate the data correctly. If i write in a cell, I can. But when i tab, the cell is outlined in RED and i can only ESC, which returns the cell to normal with original data. I want to be able edit the table and save the data.

What are some possible fixes or points of problem?

Comment: What does your TableModel return for `isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)`?

Answer (score 3):

`CellEditor` accepting inputed value that corresponding with [Class.types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), for example

- in the case that `Column Class is Number`, then `CellEditor` accepting only [Numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), `decimal separator` and `negative sign`,
- most complicated could be input correct value for plain [Date Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)
- depends of `Class.types` and `Formatters` that are sets in your `BeanTableModel`
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: my columns are strings, does that hint at anythign else?

Answer (score 2):

> the cell is outlined in *red*.

As illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513), this is the behavior of the [default editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), `JTable.GenericEditor`. This suggests that your `TableModel` has an incorrect implementation of `getColumnClass()`, as others have suggested. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), which may help isolate the problem.

Comment: _TableModel has an incorrect implementation of isCellEditable()_ that can't be not what you mean :)