# Swing dependent components and event system

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablecelleditor

I have to build a complex GUI in JAVA with Swing (for the moment I have near 80 classes).
The graphic partv of the application is split as follows: a first series of tabs (eg "Management", "Administration", "Configuration"), then a second level (for example, "User", "Group", "Game"). For now I'm two grade levels (one for each level of tabs). The next level is a JPanel that manages a business object (my whole GUI is built around my business model), at this level there are 2 type of JPanel: who manages simple objects (eg, "User", "Category" , "Game", "Level") and those which manages objects "composite primary key" (eg "User_Game" which represent the form of a double-entry table for each game level for all users).
My second level of tabs can contain multiple JPanel.
When my JPanel manages a single object is composed of a JTable and two buttons (Add and Remove) on which I put events, if not it is a simple JTable. When I have foreign keys (eg "Group" for "User" and "Category" to "Game" or "Level" to "User_Game") it is a JComboBox that takes its information directly from JTableModel. When it comes to managing a JTable object to "composite primary key" the columns and rows also directly dependent models (eg "Game" and "User" "User_Game").
Each has its own JTable model that deals with the persistence layer (Hibernate for information) and other TableModel.
To manage changes (such as adding, modifying or deleting a "User") I use the code below:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.beans.*;

/*
 *  This class listens for changes made to the data in the table via the
 *  TableCellEditor. When editing is started, the value of the cell is saved
 *  When editing is stopped the new value is saved. When the oold and new
 *  values are different, then the provided Action is invoked.
 *
 *  The source of the Action is a TableCellListener instance.
 */
public class TabCellListener implements PropertyChangeListener, Runnable
{
    private JTable table;
    private Action action;

    private int row;
    private int column;
    private Object oldValue;
    private Object newValue;

    /**
     *  Create a TableCellListener.
     *
     *  @param table   the table to be monitored for data changes
     *  @param action  the Action to invoke when cell data is changed
     */
    public TabCellListener(JTable table, Action action)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.action = action;
        this.table.addPropertyChangeListener( this );
        this.table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new ModelListenerTableGui(this.table, this.action));
    }

    /**
     *  Create a TableCellListener with a copy of all the data relevant to
     *  the change of data for a given cell.
     *
     *  @param row  the row of the changed cell
     *  @param column  the column of the changed cell
     *  @param oldValue  the old data of the changed cell
     *  @param newValue  the new data of the changed cell
     */
    private CellListenerTableGui(JTable table, int row, int column, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.oldValue = oldValue;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the column that was last edited
     *
     *  @return the column that was edited
     */
    public int getColumn()
    {
        return column;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the new value in the cell
     *
     *  @return the new value in the cell
     */
    public Object getNewValue()
    {
        return newValue;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the old value of the cell
     *
     *  @return the old value of the cell
     */
    public Object getOldValue()
    {
        return oldValue;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the row that was last edited
     *
     *  @return the row that was edited
     */
    public int getRow()
    {
        return row;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the table of the cell that was changed
     *
     *  @return the table of the cell that was changed
     */
    public JTable getTable()
    {
        return table;
    }
//
//  Implement the PropertyChangeListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  A cell has started/stopped editing

        if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            if (table.isEditing())
                processEditingStarted();
            else
                processEditingStopped();
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Save information of the cell about to be edited
     */
    private void processEditingStarted()
    {
        //  The invokeLater is necessary because the editing row and editing
        //  column of the table have not been set when the "tableCellEditor"
        //  PropertyChangeEvent is fired.
        //  This results in the "run" method being invoked

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( this );
    }
    /*
     *  See above.
     */
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        row = table.convertRowIndexToModel( table.getEditingRow() );
        column = table.convertColumnIndexToModel( table.getEditingColumn() );
        oldValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
        newValue = null;
    }

    /*
     *  Update the Cell history when necessary
     */
    private void processEditingStopped()
    {
        newValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);

        //  The data has changed, invoke the supplied Action

        if ((newValue == null && oldValue != null) || (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)))
        {
            //  Make a copy of the data in case another cell starts editing
            //  while processing this change

            CellListenerTableGui tcl = new CellListenerTableGui(
                getTable(), getRow(), getColumn(), getOldValue(), getNewValue());

            ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(
                tcl,
                ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                "");
            action.actionPerformed(event);
        }
    }
}
```

And the following action:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.Action;

public class UpdateTableListener<N> extends AbstractTableListener implements Action
{
    protected boolean enabled;
    public UpdateTableListener(AbstractTableGui<N> obs)
    {
        super(obs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (null != e && e.getSource() instanceof CellListenerTableGui)
        {
            TabCellListener tcl = (TabCellListener)e.getSource();

            this.obs.getModel().setValueAt(tcl.getNewValue(), tcl.getRow(), tcl.getColumn());
            int sel = this.obs.getModel().getNextRequiredColumn(tcl.getRow());

            if (sel == -1)
                this.obs.getModel().save(tcl.getRow());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void putValue(String arg0, Object arg1)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener arg0)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean arg0)
    {
        this.enabled = arg0;

    }

}
```

This code works well, data are well persisted.
Then I add this code to refresh dependent components:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.Action;

public class ChangeTableListener implements Action
{

    protected AbstractTableGui table;

    public ChangeTableListener(AbstractTableGui table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        this.table.getModel().fireTableDataChanged();
        this.table.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void putValue(String arg0, Object arg1)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean arg0)
    {
    }
}
```

My TableModel.fireTableDataChanged rebuild JTable content (calle super.fireTableDataChanged and fireTableStructureChanged), JTable.repaint reset the Renderers, and it works for Combobox (forein keys) and it update well title on double-entry tables, but it can't add or delete columns or rows on double-entry tables.
Moreover I see more high latency if there is the slightest change.

My question is simple: how do you manage inter-dependent components?

For your help,
In advance,
Thanks.

Edit :
Here an example of TableCellEditor.

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TextColumnEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{

    public TextColumnEditor()
    {
        super(new JTextField());
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing()
    {
        Object v = this.getCellEditorValue();
        if(v == null || v.toString().length() == 0)
        {
            this.fireEditingCanceled();
            return false;
        }
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }
}
```

An example of TableModel :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GroupModelTable extends AbstractModelTable<Groups>
{
    protected GroupsService service;

    public GroupModelTable(AbstractTableGui<Groups> content)
    {
        super(content, new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<Groups>());
        this.headers.add("Group");
        this.content.setModel(this);
        this.service = new GroupsService();
        this.setLines(this.service.search(new Groups()));
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        switch (columnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                return this.lines.get(rowIndex).getTitle();
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object aVal, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        switch (columnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                this.lines.get(rowIndex).setTitle(aVal.toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

     @Override
     public Groups getModel(int line, int column)
     {
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     public Groups getModel(int line)
     {
         return this.lines.get(line);
     }

     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
     {
        return true;
     }

    @Override
    public GroupModelTableGui newLine()
    {
        this.lines.add(new Groups());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNextRequiredColumn(int row)
    {
        Groups g = this.getModel(row);
        if (g != null && g.getTitle() != null && g.getTitle().length() > 0)
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(int row)
    {
        Groups g = this.getModel(row);
        if (g != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (g.getId() == null)
                    this.service.create(g);
                else
                    this.service.update(g);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeRow(int row)
    {
        Groups g = this.getModel(row);
        if (g != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (g.getId() != null)
                    this.service.delete(g);

                super.removeRow(row);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of Table :

```
public class GroupTable extends AbstractTable<Groups>
{
    public GroupTable()
    {
        new GroupModelTableGui(this);
        new CellListenerTableGui(this.getContent(), new UpdateTableListenerGui<Groups>(this));
        this.getContent().getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new TextColumnEditorGui());
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you to understand :/

Comment: too lazy to give it more than a cursory look, so just a couple of comments: a) never-ever (as in _reeeally never_) fire an event on behalf of a model, that's its own core responsibility. b) there's never-ever (same degree as above :) a necessity to call repaint on the model's view - if that appears to fix something, the model doesn't notify its listeners correctly c) in an editor implementation, don't second guess the client's intention - if the edited value isn't valid, return false not more d) implement an Action immutably disabled is useless - well-behaved clients must not perform it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TabCellListener` is unfamiliar to me. Your `TableCellEditor` should *not* interact with the `TableModel` directly. It should implement `getTableCellEditorComponent()` and `getCellEditorValue()`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513). When the editor concludes, the model will have the new value. Your `TableModel` should handle persistence. More than one view may listen to a single `TableModel` via `TableModelListener`.

Addendum: Your `CellEditor`, `TextColumnEditor`, probably shouldn't invoke `fireEditingCanceled()`. Pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> should be sufficient to revert the edit, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513). You might also look at the related [tutorial section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext) and [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFTFEditDemoProject/src/components/IntegerEditor.java).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I add some code I hope this will give you a a better view of the problem. Has you can see, my TableCellEditor doesn't interact directly with my TableModel, so I am good on this part. I will try to replace my TabCellListener by a TableModelListener.

Comment: I've elaborated above, but I still don't understand the problem; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) from you may help. Out of context, I don't understand your other derivations.

Comment: I worked hard, I rebuild all the event system since my first post, but it isn't a bag thing, the number of events générated was divided by 100, so my application is significantly faster. Thanks for that. My last problem is when I try to add, delete or rename a column, the modification doesn't appears.