# How to set color to cells in JTable according to their value?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm trying to set the color of a number in a cell to red, if its negative, and to green if it's positive.

Here is my table:

```
private void setTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames) {
    table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames) {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {                
                return false;               
        };
    };
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(60);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(365);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);

    DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
}
```

The 3rd column contains the positive/negative numbers.

Comment: The secret lies here `DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();`  See [How to Use Tables - Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: A related approach is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7531513/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) that uses a JLabel as its component and change its background color according to its value (@see getTableCellRendererComponent method).

Comment: *"..JLabel as its component and change its background color"*  Don't forget to set it opaque first.  ;)