# How to change and restore the cell background in a JTable for a few seconds?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablemodel

How can I make a cell in a `JTable` change its background color when text is changed? I would like the color to change for a few seconds and then restore it to its initial background color. This is my code:

```
package GUI;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private TableModel myTableModel;

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        myTableModel = new MyTableModel();
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        table = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button.setText("jButton1");
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                buttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        table.setModel(myTableModel);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(button)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(button)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        myTableModel.setValueAt(1.40, 0, 2);myTableModel.setValueAt(1.00, 1, 2);
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton button;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable table;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private static class Rate {

        private String Currency1;

        public void setCurrency1(String Currency1) {
            this.Currency1 = Currency1;
        }

        public void setCurrency2(String Currency2) {
            this.Currency2 = Currency2;
        }

        public void setExchangeRate(Double ExchangeRate) {
            this.ExchangeRate = ExchangeRate;
        }

        public String getCurrency1() {
            return Currency1;
        }

        public String getCurrency2() {
            return Currency2;
        }

        public Double getExchangeRate() {
            return ExchangeRate;
        }
        private String Currency2;
        private Double ExchangeRate;

        public Rate() {

        }

        public Rate(String Currency1, String Currency2, Double ExchangeRate) {
            this.Currency1 = Currency1;
            this.Currency2 = Currency2;
            this.ExchangeRate = ExchangeRate;
        }

    }

    private static class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private final String[] columnNames = {"Currency1", "Currency2", "Exchange Rate"};
        private ArrayList<Rate> ratesList = new ArrayList<Rate>() {
            {
                add(new Rate("EUR", "USD", 1.13));
                add(new Rate("EUR", "GBP", 0.87));
                add(new Rate("EUR", "CHF", 1.09));
                add(new Rate("EUR", "JPY", 113.49));
                add(new Rate("EUR", "MAD", 10.86));
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Rate rate = ratesList.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    rate.setCurrency1((String) aValue);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    rate.setCurrency2((String) aValue);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rate.setExchangeRate((Double) aValue);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Rate rate = ratesList.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return rate.getCurrency1();
                case 1:
                    return rate.getCurrency2();
                case 2:
                    return rate.getExchangeRate();

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return ratesList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example lacks several essential elements: in outline,

- In a custom `TableCellEditor`, let your implementation of `stopCellEditing()`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513), start a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) having the desired delay.
- In the same implementation of `stopCellEditing()`, condition your [`TableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) to display the chosen highlight color. The subsequent invocation of `setValueAt()` should fire a suitable update event automatically.
- In the timer's `ActionListener`, `stop()` the timer and condition your `TableCellRenderer` to display the default `"Table.background"` obtained by consulting the `UIManager`. You may need to update the view, ideally by firing an appropriate event from your `TableModel`.

Comment: For more detailed guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.