# Confused by JTables & ActionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to create a JTable that when a user presses a button on the GUI it sets the values inside the if statement to that JTable.
Being quite new to java I am most likely going about this wrong. I have done some research and I believe that using DefaultTableModel would be the best.

I understand how to implement the Jtable with a set of preset values but I am struggling to understand how to set the values with a JButton.

Thanks

Comment: you should avoid using DefaultTableModel

Comment: @vitorfs: why not use DefaultTableModel if it's a simple model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [*How to Use Tables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526779/multiple-row-selection-in-jtable/4528604#4528604) shows one approach to altering the table's data model using buttons.