# Can I add JRadioButton into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jradiobutton

I tried to add `JRadioButton` into `JTable` by using `CellEditor` and `CellRenderer`, but I can't add `JRadioButton` into `JTable`. I am using NetBeans and backend MySQL. Please help me.

Edit: Thank you, but I have no idea about how to group `JRadioButton`. Can you help me?
I have 4 columns .First column cell containing item name , second column cell containing quantity,3rd and 4th column cells contiaining JRadio Buttons.Then I want to grouping 3rd and 4th column cells containing JRadio Buttons in each row

Edit:If I try to add radiobutton in the customize code of jTable by using this,

`new JRadioButton("a")` , then it'l come as, `javax.swing.JRadioButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,.....text=a],` in the column instead of button

Comment: For better guidance, Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problems you have.

Comment: See also this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11259579/230513).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear how you want to use `JRadioButton` in a `JTable`; consider these alternatives:

- Use `SINGLE_SELECTION` mode to select individual rows.

  ```
  table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  ```
- Use a column of type `Boolean.class`, which will be rendered using a `JCheckBox`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513) limits selections to a single row.
- Use a `JComboBox` as an [editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) for mutually exclusive choices *within* a row.
- Addendum: If `JRadioButton` is required, they can be added to a `JPanel`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513) due to @mKorbel.
- Addendum: If each `JRadioButton` has its own column, you can't use a `ButtonGroup` because a single button is used for all cells having the same [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). You *can* update other button(s) in the same row from your `TableModel`, which should override `setValueAt()` to enforce the single-selection rule that is usually managed by the `ButtonGroup`. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14022246/230513).
- Addendum: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259671/230513) due to @Guillaume Polet illustrates a way to manage one radio button per row.

Comment: I've migrated your new code to your question and update my answer to include a related example.

Comment: I have 4 columns .First column cell containing item name , second column cell containing quantity,3rd and 4th column cells contiaining JRadio Buttons.Then I want to grouping 3rd and 4th column cells containing JRadio Buttons in each row.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows you approach; more above.

Comment: You've un-accepted and immediately re-accepted this answer twice in the past two days. Is everything OK? An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) will help identify any remaining problems.

Comment: i have some problems remaining.

Comment: The text you show is returned by `JRadioButton#toString()`, suggesting that your renderer or your model are incorrect. Absent an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), I can only guess.