# Jtable sort by column

Tags: sorting, jtable

JTable

Header1  | Header2  | Header3

temp1    | temp1    | Boolean.FALSE

temp2    | temp2    | Boolean.TRUE

temp3    | temp3    | Boolean.FALSE

temp4    | temp4    | Boolean.TRUE

How can I sort Header3? into Boolean.TRUE first then Boolean.FALSE.

Comment: Can I know why do you want to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know to set the third column as the one to be sorted.

Referring to the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13467228/230513), you can specify the column and `SortOrder` like this for `CHECK_COL`:

```
public CheckABunch() {
    ...
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    DefaultRowSorter<DefaultTableModel, Integer> sorter =
        ((DefaultRowSorter) table.getRowSorter());
    List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(CHECK_COL, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
    sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableRowSorter for sorting. Search for it, you will get plenty of examples.

Comment: I already tried, but I dont know to set the third column as the one to be sorted.