# How to get the rows selected with checkBox on JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, tableview, fxml

I'm working on JavaFx, i have a table view  created with sceneBuilder , it contains 3 columns, one  of is for **checkBoxes** , and a button called **print_tab**, i want when i click on this button to get the **rows selected with checkBox -> true** but i don't know how to do that :

I read many exemples about callBack the table column of checkbox but can't figure out how to do that .

here is the controller :

```
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
    import javafx.util.Callback;


     public class RecapController implements Initializable{

     @FXML
     private TableView<OMission> missionTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<OMission, Boolean> checkedCol; 

      private ObservableList<OMission> UserMission = 
 FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
      private OMission mission=null;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        
         
         
         try {
            load_recap();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
         
    }

    public void load_recap(){
    

      .....

     
    checkedCol.setCellFactory(
                                CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkedCol)
                            );
                        
    checkedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("remark"));

                    checkedCol.setEditable(true);


          }


    public void print_tab() throws Exception {

                  // here is the method that the button calls , i want to get here the selected rows with checkbox -> true                  

                  }

          }
```

On class Model i have this code :

```
    public class OMission {

         private String ObjMission ;
         private Boolean remark;

         public OMission(  String objMission ) {

                 This.objMission = ObjMission ;

                 remark = false;
                           
                                    }

        public Boolean getRemark() {
            return remark;
        }

        public void setRemark(Boolean remark) {
            this.remark = remark;
        }


        public String getObjMission() {
            return ObjMission;
        }



        public void setObjMission(String objMission) {
            ObjMission = objMission;
        }
```

}

fxml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="pan" prefHeight="740.0" prefWidth="1258.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.RecapController">
   <children>
      <JFXButton layoutX="16.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#OpenMission" style="-fx-background-color: #0A4969;" text="Ajouter une nouvelle mission : " textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
      <TableView fx:id="missionTable" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="659.0" prefWidth="1226.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="612.5" text="RAPPORT DE MISSION">
                           <columns>
                                
                              
                              <TableColumn fx:id="local" prefWidth="100.0" text="Localité" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="objmission" prefWidth="243.0" text="Objet Mission" />
                              
                           </columns>
                        </TableColumn>
                    
            <TableColumn fx:id="checkedCol"  prefWidth="75.0" text="select" /> // That's the button i want to click on 
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
      <JFXButton layoutX="263.0" layoutY="25.0" onAction="#print_tab" text="print" />
      <CheckBox fx:id="SelectAll" layoutX="1154.0" layoutY="41.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />

   </children>
```

Any idea ?

**EDIT :**

```
public void print_tab() throws Exception {

         for(OMission bean : UserMission)
    {
        System.out.println(bean.getRemark()); // always getting false
        if(bean.getRemark()) {
            
            System.out.println(bean.getObjMission());
        }
    }                         

                  }
```

I tried this way, but even though i check some checkboxes i always get false not true , any idea ? at the same time i don't think it's a good to iterate all the collection ...

Comment: I can't test stuff at the moment myself, but have you tried the solutions on iterating `TableColumn`s proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815442/javafx-8-iterate-through-tableview-cells-and-get-graphics)?

Comment: Thank you i'm gonna read it now

Comment: ahh ... just seen that your sample code is very similar to that on your last quesiton - same naming violations, still not compileable .. please make it a [mcve], that is runnable as-ist (nothing to do for potential helpers but throw the code into an IDE, run and see what's wrong). And you didn't apply what you learned: table's editable is false by default, so you must set it to true somewhere. ;) On the other hand, TableColumn's editable is true by default - which you could have learned by reading the api doc ;)

Comment: @kleopatra i agree with you, i'm new to javaFX that's why , i will respect java naming this time :) Thank you

Comment: "i don't think it's a good to iterate all the collection" -> unless your collection is absolutely huge (e.g. 1 million + rows), this is a non-issue.

Comment: I see, i was thinking about using calllBack to the column , but as you said it's not a problem if it's not a huge one, which is not the case absolutely , Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement FX property pattern in `OMission` class:

```
public class OMission {

    private final StringProperty objMission = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "objMission");
    private final BooleanProperty remark = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "remark");

    public OMission(String objMission) {
        this.objMission.set(objMission);
        this.remark.set(false);
    }

    public StringProperty objMissionProperty() {
        return objMission;
    }

    public String getObjMission() {
        return objMissionProperty().get();
    }

    public void setObjMission(String objMission) {
        objMissionProperty().set(objMission);
    }

    public BooleanProperty remarkProperty() {
        return remark;
    }

    public Boolean getRemark() {
        return remarkProperty().get();
    }

    public void setRemark(Boolean remark) {
        remarkProperty().set(remark);
    }
}
```

Then you can replace the column `CellValueFactory`:

```
checkedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("remark"));
```

with:

```
checkedCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().remarkProperty());
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69166800/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68969222/230513), correctly defined properties are critical to a working table model. In this way, the button handler can iterate over the table's `ObservableList` to find selected rows. To study the problem in isolation, start from this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68969223/230513). The following changes iterate over the table model, checking the `active` property to produce the result shown:

```
Button b = new Button("Print Seleceted");
b.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    for (Person p : table.getItems()) {
        if (p.active.get()) {
            System.out.println(p.lastName.get() + ": " + p.email.get());
        }
    }
});
vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, b);
```

Console:

```
Smith: jacob.smith@example.com
Williams: ethan.williams@example.com
Brown: michael.brown@example.com
```

[image]