# Improving design by extracting multiple TableModels into a single TableModelManager

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, abstracttablemodel

I've been stuck on this particular part of my design and I'd like some input as to how I should approach it. My program consists of courses `LeerTrajecten` and elements `Elementen`. Both of these objects can exist independently, but elements can also be added to a course.
`Element` in itself is an abstract superclass of objects like `Document`, `Casus`, etc.

(1)
When an element is added to a course, a course-element `LeerTrajectenElement` is create which contains the `TrajectCode`, `ElementCode`, an own unique code consisting of the previous two fields and some other data (`DisplayNaam`, `DisplayOmschrijving`).

In the GUI (Spring), there are a few tabs (`JTabbedPane`) dedicated to managing these courses and elements. Every tab has an overview and a detailpanel. In this overview there's a `JTable` to display every existing `Element` or `Traject`.

This is merely intended as a way to put the program into perspective (`LeerTrajectElement`) and to show that there might be multiple `JTable` active at the same time, but on different tabs.

(2)
I've also got managers whose sole purpose is to manage their respective object (`LeerTrajectManager` manages `LeerTraject`, `ElementManager` manages `Element`, etc). These managers are known to the `Domeincontroller` which serves as a general façade for the entire domain. Requests from the GUI are sent to this `DomeinController` which sends the request, if it's meant for a manager, to the correct one.

That's the basic outline of my program, I'll include some diagrams as visual aid.

(1)
[image]

(2)[image]

I hope I have provided adequate information concerning the current setup of the project.
For some reason my model isn't displaying correctly, but the `DomeinController` holds the 3 managers (it isn't shown in the overview but the associations are there).

As you can see in picture 2, every manager holds a tableModel. TableModels are defined like this:

[image]

`MyAbstractTableModel` extends `AbstractTableModel` and provides basic implementation so specific implementations can derive from this class while only providing the very basic needs.

This is where we're getting to the point:
Currently every manager holds its own tableModel and we (the teacher) decided we should abstract this out into a manager. I've been working on an implementation for this, but I felt like I got something fundemental wrong: these tableModels can be generated for a few different purposes: either you want **all** elements, or you want all elements **linked to** a course, or you want all elements linked to a **specific** course, etc etc.

In order to obtain something like this, I've tried creating two `getTableModel` methods. The first one only took an enum {`LEERTRAJECT`, `ELEMENT`, `LEERTRAJECTELEMENT` } as argument, while the second one took an additional `List<E>` as argument. Doing this would allow me to generically add data to the request, data which could be gathered earlier by the appropriate manager (and thus only sending resultset data to the `TableModelManager`.

This approach ended up with a lot of `Switch` statements for every method in my `TableModelManager` to determine what should happen with it and what tableModel should be used. The code became pretty unclean so I figured that this is probably not the way I want it to be.

As to why we should introduce a manager in the first place: appearantly our tableModels are now hard linked to our respective managers and we should try to avoid this.

So, in conclusion: I have several managers, all of them holding a `TableModel` to display their respective data. I would like to centralize this by holding the current `TableModel` in a `TableModelManager` and generate tablemodels trough this object. Other managers would simply hold a reference to the `TableModelManager` and tell him the data has been changed or ask for the appropriate model.

How should I approach this?

PS: I realize this is more of a design question, so if I should place this in a different site on the stackexchange network just let me know and I'll delete this.

PPS: I'm sorry for the non-english parts, my teammates refused to use english only.

Answer (score 1):

Absent a detailed analysis,

- You may be able to salvage your `enum` approach by letting each element implement a common interface to effect a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), as oulined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15076852/230513).
- As a concrete example of using a manager, this [TestTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259671/230513) uses an instance of `MyObjectManager` to manage one radio button per row in a `JTable`.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely take a look at this!

Comment: You are welcome; take to time to review and present your findings to your team. For reference, this very simple [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513) shows that `setModel()` allows `JTable` to display any (valid) `TableModel`.