# Related to checkbox in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, buttongroup

I am using a table to display data.

I am providing checkbox to each row of a table to perform some operations based on selection. When I did like that, I am able to check multiple rows.

But my requirement is, at any point of time I should check only one checkbox. To be precise, I need the behavior of Buttongroup to all checkboxes in table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use checkboxes, I assume your `TableModel` holds a boolean for those checkboxes. It should be trivial to move the logic for the single selection to the `TableModel`.

If you do not need the checkboxes but just want to operate on the selected rows (see `JTable#getSelectedRows`), you can adjust the `ListSelectionModel` which is present on the `JTable` to only allow for single selection (see [`ListSelectionModel#SINGLE_SELECTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#SINGLE_SELECTION))

Answer (score 2):

[`CheckOne`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513) is a complete example that simply clears all check boxes in a specific column and sets the new value. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259671/230513) uses `JRadioButton`.