# How to create a custom model that controls the display of check boxes?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPanel` containing a list of `JCheckBox` fields, and I want them to be displayed in a specific order. I was told that a view model can be created to sort those check boxes. I am very new to Swing and don't know how to proceed further. I couldn't exactly find any source in internet. Can someone help me to figure out a way for implementing the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add them in the order you want them displayed. If you want more control, you could use a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: cant add them in the order I wanted to (because of some limitations).

Comment: Then use a layout manager which allows you to control the positioning, like GridBagLayout

Comment: GridBagLayout is used for view positioning in a screen right ? My use case is, I have list of check boxes in a panel, and they will be dynamically enabled/disabled during the runtime. I want all these check boxes to be sorted based on their status dynamically (enabled first and then disabled).

Comment: Then, you'll probably want a custom layout manager ... and I'd hate to be your end user :P

Comment: Do you mean a _model_ for the data that controls the display in the view?

Comment: @trashgod : yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create a *model* for the data that controls the display in the *view*. One approach would be to create a suitable `TableModel` for the model and use [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for the view. Your `TableCellRenderer` can condition the display's color and enabled state; your implementation of `Comparable` will define the sort order.

In this compete [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), `class DataModel extends AbstractTableModel` to manage a `List<Value>`, and `Value implements Comparable<Value>` by forwarding to `Double`. Your implementation would add an attribute for `Enabled` and include it in your implementation of the required methods. In outline,

```
private static class Value implements Comparable<Value> {

    private Boolean selected;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private Double value;

    public Value(Boolean selected, Boolean enabled, Double value) {
        this.selected = selected;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Value v) {…}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object v) {…}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {…}
}
```

This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259671/230513) uses an instance of `MyObjectManager` to manage mutual exclusion among radio button.