# using JList of Swing

Tags: java, swing, list, jradiobutton

I have a 3 Jlist, the first contain the name of application. the second is used to put the name of application to install, the third the name of application to uninstall. but it is not  beautiful. I would like to have one list with two list of radio button for each List we can choose install or uninstall but i don't know how to do that in swing.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `JTable`, take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: I think. It is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You might look at a two-column `JTable`, with the name in the first column and a `JComboBox` in the second. The `JComboBox` would specify `install`, `uninstall` or `unchanged`, defaulting to `unchanged`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) shows how to specify a `DefaultCellEditor` having a `JComboBox`.  See [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more. Some related alternatives are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11173600/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the scenario quite clearly.
Try this out.
Take 2 `JRadioButton`, one `JButtonGroup` and 3 `JList`.
Set *buttonGroup* property of those 2 radio buttons to that `JButtonGroup`. Then write codes on `onClick` event of each radio button to enable the corresponding JList and disable the other `JList`.
I hope this will help.