# Unstable program of JCheckbox in JTable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, jcheckbox

I have  a GUI that has`JCheckbox` in `JTable` where the table is populated data with database with help of vector.

I am providing the code below for extracting data from database:

```
 try {
  PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("select * from ProductInformation where     CustomerName='"+cust_name+"'");

     Vector<Vector<String>> historyVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
             rs = pre.executeQuery();

   while(rs.next())
    {
    Vector<String> history = new Vector<String>();
    serial_no=rs.getString("SerialNumber");

    history.add(serial_no);
    history.add(rs.getString("Model"));
    history.add(rs.getString("InvoiceNumber"));
    history.add(rs.getString("Location"));

         historyVector.add(history);
      }
            data=historyVector;

            header = new Vector<String>();

    header.add("Serial No"); 
    header.add("Model");
    header.add("Invoice no"); 
    header.add("Location");
    header.add("ASC");
    header.add("AMC");

       amcAscResult();
    mainframe.add(amcascresult);
    mainframe.remove(amc);
    mainframe.validate();
    mainframe.repaint();
    mainframe.pack();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

I am experiencing a problem like when I run the program I select some `JCheckbox` it returns Null pointer exception.
Some times it runs as expected.

My code for inserting records into table

```
 amcasc_table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        data,header
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, true, true
        };
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /*@Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }*/
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;
                case 3:
                    return String.class;
                default:
                    return Boolean.class;
            }
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(amcasc_table);
```

And for getting values of `JCheckbox`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <amcasc_table.getRowCount(); i++) {
 boolean isChecked = (Boolean) amcasc_table.getValueAt(i, 4);

 if (isChecked) {
    //get the values of the columns you need.

 String value = (String) amcasc_table.getValueAt(i, 0);

 System.out.println(value);

}
}
```

What is the mistake I have done and can anyone help me how to overcome this?

SSCCE

```
     import java.awt.HeadlessException;
     import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
     import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
     import java.sql.*;
     import java.text.DateFormat;
     import java.text.Format;
     import java.text.ParseException;
     import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
     import java.util.Date;
     import java.util.Properties;
     import java.util.Vector;
     import javax.mail.*;
     import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
     import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
     import javax.swing.*;


public class Combined {
Session session;
JFrame mainframe,mailframe;
JPanel firstpane, newsales, confirmnewsales, checkserialno, producthistory, newcomplaint, newcomplaintentry;
JPanel  confirmcomplaint,sendmail,generatereport,generatereportresult,amc,amcascresult,amcascconfirm;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu menu;
JMenuItem menuItem;
JMenu submenu;
JRadioButtonMenuItem rbMenuItem;
JCheckBoxMenuItem cbMenuItem;
Connection con,con1;
Statement st,st1;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Format mmFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
DateFormat yyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");
DateFormat ddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
String invoice_no;
String serial_no;
String model;
String cust_name;
String cust_location;
String amc_status;
Date date_of_purchase;
Date amc_start_date;
Date amc_end_date;
String amcend_date;
String amcstart_date;
ButtonModel amc_status_model;
String query;
ResultSet rs,rs1;
Date dateofpurchase;
String date_ofpurchase;
String query1;
String eng_name;
String problem_description;
String contact_person;
String contact_no;
String calldate;
String callmonth;
String callyear;
String callno;
int inccallno;
String lastcallno;
String query3, query4, query5;
String lastcalldate;
String sinccallno;
String db;
String toaddress;
String subject;
String messagebody;
String warrantystatus;
Vector<Vector<String>> data; 
Vector<String> header; 
String callstatus;
int no_of_calls = 0;

public Combined() {
    connect();
    framegen();

}

private void framegen() {
    mainframe = new JFrame("Product Maintenance and Support Software");
    //Create the menu bar.
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //Build the first menu.
    menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "The only menu in this program that has menu items");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    //a group of JMenuItems
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("A text-only menu item",
            KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_1, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "This doesn't really do anything");
    menu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Both text and icon",
            new ImageIcon("images/middle.gif"));
    menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    menu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem(new ImageIcon("images/middle.gif"));
    menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    menu.add(menuItem);

     //a group of radio button menu items
    menu.addSeparator();
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("A radio button menu item");
    rbMenuItem.setSelected(true);
    rbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    group.add(rbMenuItem);
    menu.add(rbMenuItem);

    rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Another one");
    rbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    group.add(rbMenuItem);
    menu.add(rbMenuItem);

    //a group of check box menu items
    menu.addSeparator();
    cbMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("A check box menu item");
    cbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    menu.add(cbMenuItem);

    cbMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Another one");
    cbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    menu.add(cbMenuItem);

    //a submenu
    menu.addSeparator();
    submenu = new JMenu("A submenu");
    submenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("An item in the submenu");
    menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_2, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    submenu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Another item");
    submenu.add(menuItem);
    menu.add(submenu);

   //Build second menu in the menu bar.
    menu = new JMenu("Another Menu");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "This menu does nothing");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    mainframe.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    firstpane();
    mainframe.add(firstpane);
    mainframe.pack();
    mainframe.setVisible(true);
    mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    mainframe.setResizable(false);

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Combined com = new Combined();

}

private void connect() {
    try {
        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        String db1 = "jdbc:odbc:solaris";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db1);
        st = con.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("database connection failed");
    }
}



private void firstpane() {
    firstpane = new JPanel();

    addnewsales_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    newcomplaint_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    calllist_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    generatereport_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    serialnocheck_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    solaris_logo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Support_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    putAMC_button = new javax.swing.JButton();

    firstpane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    addnewsales_button.setText("Add New Sales Entry");

    addnewsales_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           // addnewsales_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    newcomplaint_button.setText("New Complaint");
    newcomplaint_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           // newcomplaint_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    calllist_button.setText("Call list");
    calllist_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           // calllist_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    generatereport_button.setText("Generate Report");
    generatereport_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            //generatereport_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    serialnocheck_button.setText("Serial Number Check");
    serialnocheck_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           // serialnocheck_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    solaris_logo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/combined/image/Solaris_logo.jpg"))); // NOI18N

    Support_label.setText("Support Section");

    putAMC_button.setText("Put AMC");
    putAMC_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            putAMC_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(firstpane);
    firstpane.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(calllist_button).addGap(41, 41, 41).addComponent(putAMC_button).addGap(28, 28, 28).addComponent(generatereport_button).addGap(74, 74, 74)).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(solaris_logo).addGap(132, 132, 132)))).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(20, 20, 20).addComponent(addnewsales_button).addGap(44, 44, 44).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(Support_label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addContainerGap()).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(serialnocheck_button).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 43, Short.MAX_VALUE).addComponent(newcomplaint_button).addGap(23, 23, 23)))));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
              layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(32, 32, 32).addComponent(solaris_logo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(Support_label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 72, Short.MAX_VALUE).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(addnewsales_button).addComponent(serialnocheck_button).addComponent(newcomplaint_button)).addGap(28, 28, 28).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(calllist_button).addComponent(generatereport_button).addComponent(putAMC_button)).addGap(34, 34, 34)));

}


private void putAMC_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    amc();
    mainframe.add(amc);
    mainframe.remove(firstpane);
    mainframe.validate();
    mainframe.repaint();
    mainframe.pack();
}

private void amc() {

    amc=new JPanel();
    custname_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    custname_txtbox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    amc_search_button = new javax.swing.JButton();

    amc.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "AMC Sign up", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, null, new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    custname_label.setText("Enter the Customer Name");

    amc_search_button.setText("Search");
    amc_search_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            amc_search_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(amc);
    amc.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(custname_label)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(custname_txtbox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(116, 116, 116)
            .addComponent(amc_search_button)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(46, 46, 46)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(custname_label)
                .addComponent(custname_txtbox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(51, 51, 51)
            .addComponent(amc_search_button)
            .addContainerGap(136, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}

private void amc_search_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    cust_name=custname_txtbox.getText().trim();

       try {
            PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("select * from   ProductInformation where CustomerName='"+cust_name+"'");

            Vector<Vector<String>> historyVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
             rs = pre.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
{
 Vector<String> history = new Vector<String>();
 serial_no=rs.getString("SerialNumber");
 System.out.println("here");//Empid
 history.add(serial_no);
 history.add(rs.getString("Model"));
 history.add(rs.getString("InvoiceNumber"));
 history.add(rs.getString("Location"));



     historyVector.add(history);
   }

            data=historyVector;

            header = new Vector<String>();
    header.add("Serial No"); 
    header.add("Model");
    header.add("Invoice no"); 
    header.add("Location");
    header.add("ASC");
    header.add("AMC");




       amcAscResult();
    mainframe.add(amcascresult);
    mainframe.remove(amc);
    mainframe.validate();
    mainframe.repaint();
    mainframe.pack();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }


}

private void amcAscResult() {
    amcascresult=new JPanel();
    custname_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    custname_var_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    location_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    custlocation_var_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    amcasc_table = new javax.swing.JTable();
    putamcasc_button = new javax.swing.JButton();

    amcascresult.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Put AMC"));

    custname_label.setText("Customer Name :");

    custname_var_label.setText(cust_name);

    location_label.setText("Location :");

    custlocation_var_label.setText("<location>");

    amcasc_table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        data,header
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, true, true
        };
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /*@Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }*/
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;
                case 3:
                    return String.class;
                default:
                    return Boolean.class;
            }
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(amcasc_table);

    putamcasc_button.setText("Put AMC/ASC");
    putamcasc_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            putamcasc_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(amcascresult);
    amcascresult.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(putamcasc_button)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(custname_label)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(custname_var_label)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(location_label)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(custlocation_var_label))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(custname_label)
                .addComponent(custname_var_label)
                .addComponent(location_label)
                .addComponent(custlocation_var_label))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(putamcasc_button))
    );
}

private void putamcasc_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    for (int i = 0; i <amcasc_table.getRowCount(); i++) {
 boolean isChecked = (Boolean) amcasc_table.getValueAt(i, 4);

 if (isChecked) {
    //get the values of the columns you need.

 String value = (String) amcasc_table.getValueAt(i, 0);

 System.out.println(value);

  }
}
    amcAscConfirm();
    mainframe.add(amcascconfirm);
    mainframe.remove(amcascresult);
    mainframe.validate();
    mainframe.repaint();
    mainframe.pack();
}


private void amcAscConfirm() {
    amcascconfirm=new JPanel();
     confirm_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    finish_button = new javax.swing.JButton();

    amcascconfirm.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Confirmation   of AMC/ASC"));

    confirm_label.setText("AMC/ASC has been availed for the machines selected");

    finish_button.setText("Finish");
    finish_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            finish_button1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(amcascconfirm);
    amcascconfirm.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                    .addComponent(confirm_label)
                    .addGap(0, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,   layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(finish_button)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(59, 59, 59)
            .addComponent(confirm_label)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 169, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(finish_button)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
}

 private void finish_button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

     mainframe.add(firstpane);
     mainframe.remove(amcascconfirm);
     mainframe.validate();
     mainframe.repaint();
     mainframe.pack();
}

private javax.swing.JLabel confirm_label;
private javax.swing.JButton finish_button;
private javax.swing.JTable amcasc_table;
private javax.swing.JLabel custlocation_var_label;
private javax.swing.JLabel custname_label;
private javax.swing.JLabel custname_var_label;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JLabel location_label;
private javax.swing.JButton putamcasc_button;
 private javax.swing.JButton amc_search_button;
private javax.swing.JTextField custname_txtbox;

private javax.swing.JLabel Support_label;
private javax.swing.JButton addnewsales_button;
private javax.swing.JButton calllist_button;
private javax.swing.JButton generatereport_button;
private javax.swing.JButton newcomplaint_button;
private javax.swing.JButton putAMC_button;
private javax.swing.JButton serialnocheck_button;
private javax.swing.JLabel solaris_logo;
 }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   Though it sounds suspiciously like the code is attempting to update the GUI from outside the EDT.

Comment: Also 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough. 3) Please take care when editing your question, to always use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17597951/edit) link below the question.  It preserves the edits of other people, that way.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added the SSCCE for my question

Comment: *"SSCCE

  `private void amc_search_buttonActionPerformed(`"* An SSCCE is one source file **with** imports, a class name and a `main(String[])` method.

Comment: But @AndrewThompson i am afraid that is around 1500 lines of code..

Comment: Did you actually *read* the content of the link I posted?  If not, please do.  If so, please go back and *read it again.*  If there is *anything* you do not understand in that document, feel free to ask.  I am well placed to explain.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am updating the SSCCE with my program with unneccsary modules leftout... my problem is in "put AMC" module

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am done with updating the code.. I am sorry if I had done some mistake again !!

Comment: 573 LOC.. :-(  Good luck with it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson mostly the placement of components in the panel would have taken most lines of code :(

Comment: Well let me think.. *"JCheckbox in JTable"*  That's two.  You need a `JScrollPane`, 3.  Those and a `JFrame` should do it.  About 30 LOC to put the components together, I'd estimate.  The table models/logic etc. are another matter.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am using Netbeans IDE GUI designer though

Comment: *"I am using Netbeans IDE GUI designer though"*  Perhaps it is time you stopped being a 'slave to your IDE' & actually figured out [how to code a GUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry I will use that from next time .. :)

Comment: I'll look to help ..next time.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself that the problem was in

```
return Boolean.class;
```

It returns null if the checkbox is not selected since it is a Wrapper Class.

I sorted it out with ..
if null is returned I initialised the boolean variable to false.

that solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Among the 700+ lines of your incomplete example, several issues stand out:

- The word *sometimes*  suggests incorrect synchronization; verify that all Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Ensure that your `TableModel` returns `Boolean.class` from `getColumnClass()` for the checkbox column, rather than merely by `default`; complete examples using `DefaultTableModel` may be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164751/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513).
- Don't *replace* components, e.g. `amc` in your first fragment and `amcascconfirm` in your *magnum opus*; update the corresponding model of the contained component.
- Verify correct query results independently of your program; `select *` is particularly troublesome if the schema mutates.