# How to set the alignment of data in Defaulttablemodel JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, alignment

I have this code wherein i am inserting string data dynamically to `JTable` as `Object` type data. I want to align the data inserted to table to centre. Here goes my code

```
private String[] COLUMNS = {"FAMILY MEMBERS", "STAR (NAKSHATRA)"};
           private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, 0){
               public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
               }

           };

           private JTable table = new JTable(model);   
public void addRow(String memb, String star) {
              Object[] row = new Object[2];
              row[0]=memb;
              row[1]=star;
              model.addRow(row);
           }
```

---

I searched this forum for similar query but in vain. any hint on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164751/230513) shows how to use a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` to effect `setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER)`. See also this tutorial section on how [renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) are selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are Strings to begin with, and the default renderer is just going to call `.toString` on the objects any way, why not use `String[]` instead of `Object[]`?

To answer your question, subclass `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer` (which subclasses `JLabel`) and set the alignment there (`setHorizontalTextPosition`). Then assign that renderer to the table, columns, or cells appropriately.

Use a single renderer for multiple cells. Once a value is rendered, the table will reuse it safely.

Comment: `setHorizontalTextPosition` isnt defined for `table` :(

Comment: and I am not inserting JLabel to the table here. Just objects

Answer (score 0):

```
  //  Try this .....

    private String[] COLUMNS = {"FAMILY MEMBERS", "STAR (NAKSHATRA)"};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, 0)              
           {
                       public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) 
                 {
                            return false;
                       }

                   };

   private JTable table = new JTable(model); 
  // To center all columns for string data 
          DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
          centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
          table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer); 
            public void addRow(String memb, String star) {
                      Object[] row = new Object[2];
                      row[0]=memb;
                      row[1]=star;
                      model.addRow(row);
           }


// Also you can use like this..
for(int i=0;i<COLUMNS;i++){
         table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
        }
```

Comment: But `table` is not accepting any methods as `setHorizontalAlignment` or any

Comment: and I am not inserting `JLabel` to the `table` here. Just objects