# How do I add to a Jtable with special font (text within a cell made bold, underlined, or even a different font color)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I understand how to add rows to a Jtable, but I don't know how to add particular styles to certain cells within those rows I. E.

When I utilise the following code:

```
Example.insertRow(0, new Object[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" });
```

I would like to know how I could make text within cell "A" underlined, cell "B" bold and cell "C" a different colour for instance "blue".

I'm sure this is possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: Please read the JTable tutorial (Google can help you find this), and read up on table cell renderers. Also search this site as similar questions get answered weekley.

Comment: Adding on the above comment, Oracle [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) are a great place to look

Comment: You can use some HTML in a custom `TableCellRenderer`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17164751/230513).