# How do I set a check box to table column when table is loading in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I have a created table (I am using NetBeans IDE). I put some data into this table when table is loading . I want to add a check box to the first column of the row with loading . Also I placed this table on a JPanel and I use `formComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)` method to load table with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTable` uses `TableModel` to retrieve column class and data.

`DefaultTableModel`, which is often used, returns 'Object.class' for all columns. If you use `DefaultTableModel`, just override `getColumnClass` method, and return right class for your columns. The default [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) will display a check box for values of type `Boolean.class`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164751/230513).

```
public class MyDefaultTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    private Class[] columnClasses;
    public Class[] getColumnClasses() {
        return columnClasses;
    }
    public void setColumnClasses(Class[] columnClasses) {
        this.columnClasses = columnClasses;
    }
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnClasses[columnIndex];
    }
}
```