# getTableCellRendererComponent not called after the adding of new row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm devloping a application with Java swing ,my problem is : if i'm adding a new row , the getTableCellRendererComponent not called , my code :

the create of table :

```
   public Tablecase() {

       SystemeBaseConnaissance = new LESSymptomesEnsembleEt();
       SystemeBaseConnaissance.lesSymptomesEnsembleEt.add("x");
       initComponents();
       jTable1.setTableHeader(null);
       jTable1.getColumn("Title 1").setCellRenderer(new brmcellrender());

       Model model = new Model();

       jTable1.setModel( model);
       model.addRow(new Object[]{"ss"});
       System.out.println(SystemeBaseConnaissance.lesSymptomesEnsembleEt.size());
    }
```

my Defaulttablemodel :

```
 class Model extends DefaultTableModel{

    public Model(){

        super();
     this.addRow(new Object[]{"sx"}  );    
       repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void addRow(Object[] rowData) {
        super.addRow(rowData); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


}
```

my DefaultCellEditor :

```
    public class brmcelleditor extends DefaultCellEditor{

    public brmcelleditor(JTextField textField) {
        super(textField);
    }
    }


     public class brmcellrender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    public brmcellrender() {
        super();
        System.out.println("mefgoudabrahim20.Tablecase.brmcellrender.<init>()");
    /**/
    }

    /*affichge */

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            System.out.println("mefgoudabrahim20.Tablecase.brmcellrender.<init>qsdqsdqsd()");
            CaseOfTable cas = new CaseOfTable() ; 
            return  ( cas) ;
        }



    }
```

Comment: A complete example using `setCellRenderer()` is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17157915/230513).

Comment: my problem in setCellRenderer() ?

Comment: If it's _not_ set, either by column or class, the default renderer will be used.

Comment: not , it's set !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: please whats reason for repaint() in DefaultTableModel, better should be search here Java Swing JTable DefaultTableModel, lots of Q&A in SSCCE / MCVE form, follows this idea (code in SSCCE / MCVE form) in future, for me this question isn't answerable

Comment: Assuming that the [example cited](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17157915/230513) works for you, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i'm adding a new row , the getTableCellRendererComponent not called

The problem is not because you add a new row.

```
jTable1.getColumn("Title 1").setCellRenderer(new brmcellrender());
Model model = new Model();
jTable1.setModel( model);
```

The problem is that you set the model after you set the renderer. When you set the model of a table the TableColumnModel and all the TableColums are recreated which means you lose the custom renderers you added to the TableColumn.

The code should be:

```
Model model = new Model();
jTable1.setModel( model);
jTable1.getColumn("Title 1").setCellRenderer(new brmcellrender());
```

Also, you would not create a new model every time you add a row. The point of adding a row is to add it to the existing model.

Finally, class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Fix your renderer name.