# add jbuttons with rows into jtable by clycking jbutton using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to insert lines and buttons to jtable while clicking on the button add using netbeans, I used JScrollPane but with only 4 buttons.How can I create a jtable with lines that contain are buttons in the last columns.

Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  You're going to need to provide a custom cell renderer and possibly a cell editor, depending on your needs. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565169/unable-to-add-two-buttons-in-a-single-cell-in-a-jtable/17565826#17565826)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a jtable with lines that contain are buttons in the last columns.

You need to add a column in the TableModel to display on the button. Then you need to use a custom renderer and editor for that column.

Check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for and class you can use.