# How to make only one checkbox selectable in JTable Column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, defaulttablemodel

I am using DefaultTableModel as follows:

```
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (COLUMNS, 0 )
  {
      @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
      {
          return (getColumnName(column).equals("Selected"));
      }

      public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
      {
          if(getColumnName(columnIndex).equals("Selected"))
              return Boolean.class;
          return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
      }     
  };
```

Now I want to make only one checkbox selectable in the column "Selected". How can this be done. I have tried following method also but its not working.

```
 public void fireTableCellUpdated(int row,int column)
 {
     if(getColumnName(column).equals("Selected"))
     {
         for(int i = 0; i<getRowCount() && i!=row;i++)
            setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, row, column);
     }
 }
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to implement a radio button functionality?

Comment: "its not working" - can you be a little more specific? Does it throw an `Exception`, or some other helpful information? What do you see?

Comment: Can i know what IDE are you using?

Comment: It throws StackOverFlow exception.

Comment: @NiteshVerma I am using JDeveloper, but does it make any difference

Comment: No, No not at all. Just gathering more facts on that.

Comment: You get `StackOverFlowException` because `setValueAt()` will result in `fireTableCellUpdated()` being called which calls the former again.

Comment: It probably throws StackOverflow because your fireTableCellUpdated mehtod cascades endlessly.

Comment: Maybe it wanted you to ask Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there any other method to handle this issue?

Comment: please whats goal there is one column??? or row??? that contains JCheckBox,

Comment: for better help soner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame, JTable and with hardoded value for TableModel

Comment: @mKorbel I have a JTable with one column as boolean.class, there can be many rows in the table but I want to make only one checkbox selected among all the rows.

Comment: @eatSleepCode 1. I have a JTable with one column as boolean.class ---> no idea from code posted, for why hells on this world is required to call fireWhatever for DeafultTableModel, don't do that, prepare (to search here for) an SSCCE, 2. but I want to make only one checkbox selected among all the rows ---> nothing special for JTable based on DefaultTableModel, everything is about to override setValueAt correctly, and by blocking, avoiding (cascaded) endless loop (based on comments here),

Comment: Some alternatives are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11173600/230513).

Comment: @mKorbel can you please give example code for implementing setValueAt method.

Answer (score 1):

- @eatSleepCode wrote @mKorbel can you please give example code for implementing setValueAt method.
- code for (OP used) DefaultTableModel,
- for code based on `AbstractTableModel` is required to hold code ordering for notifier `fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex)`;, because/otherwise nothing will be repainted in `JTables view`,
- there are a few important differencies betweens those two models and its notifiers, and (my view) there isn't reason to bothering with and to use `AbstractTableModel` for basic stuff (99pct of table models)

[image] . . . . [image] . . . . [image]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableRolloverDemo {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRolloverDemo");
    private JTable table = new JTable();
    private String[] columnNames = new String[]{"Column"};
    private Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{false}, {false}, {true}, {true},
        {false}, {false}, {true}, {true}, {false}, {false}, {true}, {true}};

    public TableRolloverDemo() {
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            private boolean ImInLoop = false;

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return Boolean.class;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    if (!ImInLoop) {
                        ImInLoop = true;
                        Boolean bol = (Boolean) aValue;
                        super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
                        for (int i = 0; i < this.getRowCount(); i++) {
                            if (i != rowIndex) {
                                super.setValueAt(!bol, i, columnIndex);
                            }
                        }
                        ImInLoop = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
                }
            }
        };
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableRolloverDemo tableRolloverDemo = new TableRolloverDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: gentle reminder (for the umpteenth time) - answer code should be as SSCCE as question code :-) Rollover effects are nice, but unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You get an stack overflow exception because setValueAt() method triggers fireTableCellUpdated() method once again and again.

Instead, try using a table listener which would listen to check box's value change and would set all other check boxes' value to false.

Comment: Wouldn´t that have the exact same effect ?

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own custom cell editor that joins all check boxes in a column in a `ButtonGroup`. here's how:

```
public class VeryComplicatedCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    private ArrayList<ButtonGroup> groups;

    public getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        growToSize(column);
        groups.get(column).add(checkBox);
        return checkBox;
    }

    private growToSize(int size) {
        groups.ensureCapacity(size);
        while (groups.size() < size)
            groups.add(new ButtonGroup());
    }
}
```

There are some complications that come from the fact that we don't know how big the table is, which are mostly taken care of in the `growToSize` method.

The way this works is by maintaining a list of `ButtonGroup`s, one for each column. The editor component for each cell is added to the button group for its column.

Comment: That´s interesting. Is it doable? Any examples out there ?

Comment: plain wrong a) doesn't comply to its contract: _must_ notify listeners when editing is terminated b) creating a new checkbox (and buttongroup) at each call - how's that supposed to solve a problem? c) not configuring the checkbox