# Toggling with Boolean (boolean) value

Tags: java, boolean

Please just my curiosity that could be used ([code example see at line 38th(code edited)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17946486/714968))

```
Boolean bol = true;
Boolean bol1 = !bol;
```

my question are

- its proper way, or is there (any) possible lack, issue why to avoid to use
- is correct result is the same for boolean and Boolean
- is there another data type in Java, where is possible toggle with expression, logical value

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I fail to understand what you are asking exactly.

Comment: Huh? Where is the question?

Comment: There is no such code at line 58.

Answer (score 6):

The second instruction will throw a NullPointerException if `bol` is null. If you're sure that the boolean is not null, then no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its ok.

Boolean can hold a third value "null", whearat boolean can only hold `true` or `false`.

If you have a function

```
public static void hi(boolean b) {...};

public static void main(String[] args){
    Boolean b = null;
    hi(b); // ... throws a NullPointerException at Runtime only
}
```

This is called autoboxing, because of the `Reflection` needs real classes with package.

Reflection also has

```
Void (realy wired in real code)
Integer
Float
Enum (sometimes)
```

Comment: What does reflection has to do with the existence of Boolean? Boolean predates reflection. It's needed mainly because collections only store objects, and becase you sometimes want a nullable Boolean.

Comment: `boolean[]` is a collection too - no explicit need for `Boolean` here, even collections can contain a `Container` to only store the boolean. But you cant use Reflection to identify `hi` without the use of `Boolean` from `hi(int b)`.

Comment: boolean[] is an array. And Boolean is the standard container to only store the boolean. As I said, Boolean exists since the very beginning of Java, when reflection didn't exist yet.

Comment: Boolean is cka wrapper. Yes Boolean exists since `JDK 1.0`, anyway you cant implement reflection without `Boolean`. Ill stroke introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the correct way, and it will work with both boolean and Boolean.

Your "another data type" might possibly be integer used to store boolean as 0 and 1, although I don't know who would do that if we have real boolean.

There, you would use this:

```
int a = 1;
int negated = 1-a;
```

Comment: or more general, you can loop through a list of `n` options by `(a+1)%n`