# Swing JTable, exception while removing rows from DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, defaulttablemodel

I have written the following function which i can use to can remove the rows from the DefaultTableModel:

```
private static void removeTableRows(JTable tableToClear){
    DefaultTableModel defaultModel = 
            (DefaultTableModel) tableToClear.getModel();
    int rows = defaultModel.getRowCount();

      while(rows>0) {
         defaultModel.removeRow(0);
      }
      String[] test = {"a","b","c"};
     defaultModel.addRow(test);
}
```

which throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:632)
    at org.swx.nursing.tools.gui.DefaultTableGui$2.tableChanged(DefaultTableGui.java:217)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:280)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:245)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:447)
    at org.swx.nursing.tools.gui.DefaultTableGui.removeTableRows(DefaultTableGui.java:357)
    at org.swx.nursing.tools.gui.DefaultTableGui.actionPerformed(DefaultTableGui.java:330)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6297)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6062)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

The tablechanged method is overridden as follows:

```
 //Add table cell listener
    model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){

        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
             int row = e.getFirstRow();
             int col = e.getColumn();
             TableModel tableModel = (TableModel)e.getSource();
             Object data = null ;

             try{
                 data = tableModel.getValueAt(row, col);
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 LOGGER.error("Failed to access table data: "+ex.getMessage());
             }

             boolean ishotKeyColEmpty = tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString().isEmpty();
             boolean ishTypeColEmpty = tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2).toString().isEmpty();     
             /*
              * If the Application path column is empty, then clear the contents from
              * the hotKey and Type cells for this row 
              * 
              */
             if(data != null 
                     && data.toString().equals("") 
                     && !ishotKeyColEmpty 
                     && !ishTypeColEmpty) {
                 tableModel.setValueAt("", row, 0);
                 tableModel.setValueAt("", row, 2);
             }      
        }
    });
```

I am not sure what is causing this exception..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are 2 problems in your code .

1)try to get values from none existing row/column - in `modellistner`.

2)continuously remove rows without stopping even when there are no more rows-in `removeTableRows` method

---

let me explain 2nd error first.

`2)`  inside the while loop you are not update row count.you are getting row count but this while loop condition never become false.for example you have 3 rows and count is 3 now inside while loop you are checking `(rows > 0)` no matter how much time it loops it's always true so when loop runs 4th time you get a error because there is no more rows to remove. you have to recount the row count

change method to

```
DefaultTableModel defaultModel= (DefaultTableModel) tableToClear.getModel();
int rows = defaultModel.getRowCount();
while (rows > 0) {
       defaultModel.removeRow(0);
       rows = defaultModel.getRowCount(); // this is very important
}
String[] test = {"a", "b", "c"};
defaultModel.addRow(test);
```

note:

you can use method `defaultModel.RowCount(0);` method to remove all rows .you don't need to do it using a loop

`1)`  make sure row and col is 0 or more than it .because those can be -1 when they doesn't exist.then you will get lot of errors

so this line is important

```
 (row >= 0 && col >= 0){}
```

and also here

```
boolean ishotKeyColEmpty = tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString().isEmpty();
```

you have to safely check `getValueAt(row, 0)` is not null before call 
 `toString().isEmpty()` method.
 in your

complete code

```
addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                int col = e.getColumn();
                TableModel tableModel = (TableModel) e.getSource();
                Object data = null;

                try {
                    if (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
                        data = tableModel.getValueAt(row, col);

                        boolean ishotKeyColEmpty = false;
                        boolean ishTypeColEmpty = false;
                        if (tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0) != null) {
                            ishotKeyColEmpty = tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString().isEmpty();
                        }
                        if (tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2) != null) {
                            ishTypeColEmpty = tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2).toString().isEmpty();
                        }

                        if (data != null && data.toString().equals("") && !ishotKeyColEmpty && !ishTypeColEmpty) {
                            tableModel.setValueAt("", row, 0);
                            tableModel.setValueAt("", row, 2);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this to me...worked like a charm! (and I have tried so many things to fix it :/)

Comment: @Rookie good .but there was a problem in my side in previous answer .so i updated it. actually you should check `(row >= 0 && col >= 0)` in model listner.i updated code for model listner

Comment: let me explain 2nd error first. & change method to == DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(0) reseting all ..

Comment: @mKorbel what ?i don't get it

Comment: whats reason to avoids null value from XxxTableModel, I can't see any thats make me some sense

Comment: have you any issue to search about DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(0)

Comment: @mKorbel i stated it's easy to use `rowcount` than removing rows using that kind of method

Comment: or removin must be recrusive, by decreasing an index from max to zero imdex , have to accept that many array has the same problem with

Comment: @mKorbel `tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0)` can be null  so if we call toString isempty there would be a nullpointer exception .isn't it?but of course it depend on how data add to the table .

Comment: by trying to put all together [override getValueAt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17946486/714968) inside XxxTableModel [rather than ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event), for null + isEmpty or "" to use some of attempts about ternary operator, btw JTables view hasn't some issue with null, empty

Comment: @mKorbel TNX FOR YOUR COMMENT .it will helps to op as well