# How do I retrieve the component type used at a specific cell in a JTable?

Tags: java, jtable, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I've created a `JTable` whose columns contain a variety of different components. The last five columns either contain nothing (a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` with no value) or a `JRadioButton` using a custom renderer and editor. The renderer creates and returns a new radioButton in the cells I need one, and I want to access these radio buttons from my panel class to add them to a `ButtonGroup`. I am using the following piece of code that I wrote:

```
protected void setButtonGroups() {
    buttonGroups = new ArrayList<ButtonGroup>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
        ButtonGroup currentGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int j = 0; j < tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            if (table.getComponentAt(i, j) != null) {
                    currentGroup.add((JRadioButton)table.getComponentAt(i, j));
                }
            }
        }
        buttonGroups.add(currentGroup);
    }
}
```

`getComponentAt()` keeps returning null regardless of what is contained in the cell, whether it be a `JCheckBox`, `JRadioButton`, `JComboBox`... everything is returned as null.

Is there an alternative way to get the cell's component? Or is there a way for me to get this to work? Thank you!

Comment: The `getComponentAt` method refers to "pixel coordinates", not to the cells of the table. Usually, the cells of the table are rendered with a renderer, but such a renderer (usually) uses the *same* component for *all* cells of one column (it's used like a "stamp", only for painting the cell contents - the components are not really "there"). You mentioned that you are creating new buttons in the renderer. This may cause problems, because the buttons may be re-created each time they are painted. You should add the code of your button-based renderer/editor (preferably, a compilable example)

Comment: @Marco13 Yes you are right.

Comment: Use a combination of JTabel#getCellRenderer and TableCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererCoomponent. This will return the physical component used by the JTable, if that render then contains sub components, you will need to further inspect the renderer component

Comment: Several alternatives are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11154378/230513).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tableModel from [table.getModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getModel%28%29). Then you can call [model.getValueAt(row,col)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)

I am not sure why you are putting Swing Components inside a JTable.  Are you using it for formatting?  If so [look into LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  If you want to edit values in a table, you might want to look into extending TableCellEditor.  If you really want to put components in your table.  Consider extending the DefaultTableCellRenderer to return your component. You will want to [override getTableCellRendererComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent%28javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int%29).