# Getting value of checkbox from jtable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a problem to get value of checkbox from jtable in java, that is when i get value by this code "table.getvalue(0,1)" then i can not get the right value.

Answer (score 3):

- returns value from `JTable` contains `JCheckBox` represents `Boolean` value,
- `toString` returns `"true" / "false"`
- more in the [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple)

Answer (score 3):

As a concrete example, I got the expected result when I added the following line to the loop in the `actionPerformed()` method of this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513):

```
System.out.println((table.getValueAt(i, CHECK_COL)));
```

Answer (score 3):

**JTable get cehckbox value when check box is checked:-**

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
              @Override
              public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                  for(int i=0;i<table.getModel().getRowCount();i++)
                  {
                    if ((Boolean) table.getModel().getValueAt(i,0))
                    {  
                      System.out.println(">\t"+table.getSelectedRow());
                      break;
                    }
                 }     
              }
    });
```