# JScrollpane only visible after maximising window Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, maximize

I'm using JScrollPane to put inside a JTable with some values, but the JScrollPane has to be invisible until user clicks on a button. But the JScrollPane remains not visible until I maximise the window manually. I've tried almost everything, .validate(); .revalidate(); .repaint()... I'm using Netbeans, and on the Custom Code of the JScrollPane I've wrote this:

```
scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
this.scrollPane.setVisible(false);
// El código de los subcomponentes y del gestor de distribución - no se muestra aquí

// El código que agrega el componente al contenedor superior - no se muestra aquí
```

Then, on MouseReleased:

```
private void botoGeneraLlistatMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    this.generaLlistat();
}
```

And on the end of generaLlistat():

```
public void generaLlistat(){{
   ...(Some code requesting data from DB)
   JTable table = new JTable(rows, headings);
   scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
   this.scrollPane.setVisible(true);
   statement.close();
   connection.close();
}
```

I will appreciate any help :)
Thank you all, and sorry about my english grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this way:

```
package stack;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Aitor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JTable table;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Add"); 

    String data[][]={{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},                        {"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"}
,{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"}
,{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"}};
    String columns[] = {"First","Second"};

    public Aitor(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,400));
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String [] a){
        Aitor aitor = new Aitor();
        aitor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        aitor.pack();
        aitor.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        panel.removeAll();
        table =new JTable(data,columns);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry about my lack of manners, I was really emotional at that moment. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You can just call `pack()` on your container after calling `setVisible(true)` and and your scrollpane will appear.

Comment: calling pack() certainly works, only downside with this approach is the UI will then go in 'Restore' mode. This creates problem if you want your UI to be in maximized mode. Using 'setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);' right after pack() should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513), although it has some of the same drawbacks mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Answer (score -1):

Try this coding if youu arer using `jframe`.

In constructor method, give

```
Jscrollpane.setVisible (false);
```

Give the particular `jscrollpane` which is associated with your `jtable` in `jframe`.

Then in actionperformed method give

```
Jscrollpane. setvisible (true); 
pack ();
```

It would help.....