# Push Button into a Combobox popup menu items Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, button, popup, jcombobox

I want to create a combobox with a button to remove menu as the picture below

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? Maybe a code snippet would help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to edit the `ComboBoxModel` *in situ*. Instead, create a model editor using a two column `JTable` and the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513). A `JDialog` would be a suitable top-level container.