# Output the content of a LinkedHasHSet into a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `LinkedHashSet` of `Book` objects. The `Book` objects have the following fields:

```
private int id;
private String author = "";
private String title = "";
private boolean isRead;
private String dateStamp = "";
private static int counter = 0;
```

I want them to go into my `JTable` which has the following columns:

```
String [] columnNames = {"ID","Title", "Author", "Status", "Date Read"};
```

How can I do this? And is it possible to have the `isRead` field being editable through a checkbox in the table?

Comment: how about iterating over your linkedHashSet and populating your Jtable ??

Comment: public static void LibToArray(){
        rowData = new Object[Book.bookList.size()][5];
        int i = 0;
        Iterator it = Book.bookList.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Book book1 = (Book)it.next();
            rowData[i][0] = (Integer)book1.getId();
            rowData[i][1] =  book1.getTitle();
            rowData[i][2] =  book1.getAuthor();
            rowData[i][3] = (Boolean)book1.getIsRead();
            rowData[i][4] =  book1.getDateStamp();
            i++;
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a class that extends `AbstractTableModel`. This class should use your `LinkedHashSet` as the data source for your table. The basic implementation provided by `AbstractTableModel` should suit most of your needs. If not, then you can override the methods you need to customize.

This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) should help you understand how `JTable` objects work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample model I have created for the table.

```
public class CustomModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private Object[] colNames ={"ID","Title", "Author", "Status", "Date Read"};
private LinkedHashSet<CustomClass> data; 

public TableModelTop() {
    this.data = getDataForDropList();
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return colNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return (String) colNames[columnIndex];
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // Set Values here;
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // Get row Values here;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    // Depending on the type of the column. Return data type;
}


/**
 * Populate the data from here.
 * @return LinkedHashSet<CustomClass>
 */
private LinkedHashSet<CustomClass> getDataForDropList() {
    LinkedHashSet<CustomClass> modelList = new  LinkedHashSet<CustomClass>();
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {

    // Create custom Object and add them to the LinkedHashSet.
            // Create a CustomClass object and add it to the LinkedHashSet
             modelList.add(customClassObject);
    }
           // Finally return the llinkedhashset
    return modelList;
}
}
```

After this just call the table model and assign this to the JTable.

```
JTable table = new JTable(new CustomModel());
```

Comment: I've suggested a way to implement `getValueAt()` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13301413/230513).

Answer (score 1):

As a concrete example of using `AbstractTableModel`, you can leverage the `toArray()` method inherited by `LinkedHashSet` to simplify the implementation of `getValueAt()`, as shown in this related [`EnvTableTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513). The default `JTable` [renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) use `JCheckBox` for `TableModel` elements of type `Boolean.class`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).