# JTable - Boolean to show as check box and must be editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, linkedhashset

Ok so I have a JTable that I populated from an LinkedHashSet of Books.

```
    public static void LibToArray(){
    rowData = new Object[Book.bookList.size()][5];
    int i = 0;
    Iterator it = Book.bookList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Book book1 = (Book)it.next();
        rowData[i][0] = (Integer)book1.getId();
        rowData[i][1] =  book1.getTitle();
        rowData[i][2] =  book1.getAuthor();
        rowData[i][3] = (Boolean)book1.getIsRead();
        rowData[i][4] =  book1.getDateStamp();
        i++;
        }
    }
```

My issue Is I want the 4th coloum to show the Boolean status as a check Box, and I want it to be able to be changed, after saving the status back to the LinkedHashSet and refreshing the table.

Sorry I am rather beginner, if you can give me some advice it will be appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate the answers but even with that answer I am still struggling, I have looked through the table tutorials as well .

Can someone please give me a more in depth explanation please :)

Comment: I cited an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13301413/230513).

Answer (score 8):

In the table model, in `getColumnClass()` return `Boolean.class` for the particular column. For example for `AbstractTableModel` or `DefaultTableModel` extensions:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 3)
        return Boolean.class;
    return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
}
```

Also, to make the cell editable, override `isCellEditable()`, for example:

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    return (col == 3); 
}
```

For more details about table models check out [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial. In the same tutorial there is an example of a table with a checkbox column.

Comment: currently i am just calling a default table like this: JTable bookTable = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);