# Coloring particular rows according to the first column values in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm trying to color particular rows according to the first column values in `JTable`, but the code below colors the rows according to the row's index. My table has simply four columns. The first column has ID numbers. I need to color the rows according to these ID numbers. For example, if the first ID is 0 and the second is also 0, both of them should be "lightGray". Any idea, please?

```
table_1 = new JTable(){
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,int Index_row, int Index_col) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer,Index_row, Index_col);
            //even index, selected or not selected
            if (Index_row % 2==0  &&  !isCellSelected(Index_row, Index_col)) {
                comp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            } else {
                comp.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            return comp;
        }
    };
```

Here is how it looks now:

[image: How it should look like]

Comment: For readability, use common Java naming conventions; for safety, use the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 6):

Your renderer is choosing the color based on the `row` parameter passed to `prepareRenderer()`. The predicate `row % 2 == 0` selects alternating rows for shading, as shown in your picture. Your question implies that you actually want to base shading on the value of column zero, `ID`. For this you need to examine the result of the `getValueAt(row, 0)`.

The exact formulation depends on your model. Using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513), the following renderer shades rows starting with the letter "T".

```
private JTable table = new JTable(dataModel) {

    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
        if (((String) dataModel.getValueAt(modelRow, 0)).startsWith("T")
            && !isCellSelected(row, col)) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        } else {
            comp.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        return comp;
    }
};
```

[image]

Addendum: @mKorbel helpfully comments on the need to convert between *model* and  *view* coordinates when sorting is enabled, as discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: +1 safer could be `int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);` for `dataModel.getValueAt`

Comment: @mKorbel: Right you are! The converse would apply to `SelectionAction`. Thank you for critical review; updated.