# JTable - extend default CellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I use a big JTable and I want to extend the CellRenderer for every Class, so every second Row has a gray Background, to make it more readable.

This gray Background for every second row should look something like this:
http://i61.tinypic.com/of3sky.png

But I still want the default alignment for every Class and the default settings for isSelected and hasFocus.

The code for the Background should be simple, something like:

```
if(row % 2 == 0){
            super.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        }
        else{
            super.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
```

But how to get the default CellRenderer for every Class, and extend it in this way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the code that you are having in the custom cell render?

Comment: Override `prepareRenderer()`, as shown int his [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14075799/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JTable Alternate Row Background](http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/default/2007/03/15/JTable-Row-Alternate-Row-Background)

> To make a JTable render each row in a different color, you just have to extend the JTable's prepareRender method.

```
JTable table = new JTable(){
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
        Component returnComp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        Color alternateColor = new Color(252,242,206);
        Color whiteColor = Color.WHITE;
        if (!returnComp.getBackground().equals(getSelectionBackground())){
            Color bg = (row % 2 == 0 ? alternateColor : whiteColor);
            returnComp .setBackground(bg);
            bg = null;
        }
        return returnComp;
};
```