# JTable not show checkbox in the boolean column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a `JTable` and I fill it with an `Object[][]` array. This array contains `boolean` and `String` values, but table does not show checkboxes (just `true` or `false`).

My code is:

```
    model =
                    new DefaultTableModel(pinFin, colNames) { 
                public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                    String type = h.getColumnsType().get(column);

                    if(type.equals("L") || type.equals("l"))
                        return Boolean.class;
                    else
                        return String.class;

                }
            };

data_table = new JTable()
    {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {                
            return false;               
        };
    };
data_table.setModel(model);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why not fill the array with values having the desired type?

Comment: I did it, the array is not string is object. For example i put a boolean value like that: pinFin[row][d] = true;....

Comment: Here's a working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).

Comment: @user1005633 and to move isCellditable to the model too

Comment: `What is wrong?` - We are not mind readers. The posted code doesn't tell us anything. We don't know what `h.getColumnsType().get(column);` does. We don't know how you use the table in your program. Post a `SSCCE` that demonstrates your problem.