# How to add JButton after a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I have a JTable with some data like this SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.Color;
class kanji{
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Kanji");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        JTable table = new JTable();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton agreg = new JButton("Agregar");         
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(get_data(), get_header());      
        JFrame hk = new JFrame("Historial de Significados");
        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("JLPT.jpg");
        ImageIcon ima = new ImageIcon("JLPT.jpg");
        table = new JTable(model){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
                switch(col){
                    case 0:
                        return false;
                    case 1:
                        return false;
                    case 2:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    default:
                        return Boolean.class;
                }
            }
        };
        DefaultTableCellRenderer r = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                setForeground(Color.blue);
                setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                setFont(new Font("Microsoft JhengHei", Font.BOLD, 50));
                return this;
            }
        };
        DefaultTableCellRenderer r2 = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                setFont(new Font("Microsoft JhengHei", Font.BOLD, 13));
                return this;
            }
        };
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(r);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(r2);
        TableColumn column = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if (i==0) {
                column.setMaxWidth(80);
                column.setMinWidth(80);
            }
            else{
                if(i==1){
                    column.setPreferredWidth(470);
                }
                else{
                    column.setMaxWidth(50);
                    column.setMinWidth(50);
                }
            }
        }
        table.setRowHeight(table.getRowHeight()+70);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(agreg, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setTitle("Historial de Significados");
        frame.setSize(1350, 700);
        frame.setIconImage(icon);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        scroll.setViewportView(table);  
    }
    public static Object [][]get_data(){
        Object data[][] = new Object[][]{
            {"\u4e00", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e01", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e02", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e03", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e04", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e05", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e06", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e07", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e08", "Uno, 1", true},
            {"\u4e09", "Uno, 1", true}
        };
        return data;
    }
    public static String []get_header(){
        String header [] = new String[]{"KANJI", "SIGNIFICADO", "Agregar"};
        return header;
    }
}
```

But I want to add 3 JButton after JTable is created, I want to have a JTable that don't take all JFrame size, in my code I get a Button but I want to have the possibility to set buttons bounds.

I've tried adding a JPanel and with another try with "setPreferredSize" where JScrollPane don't work, I mean I doesn't appear so I can't see all table content; and I also tried with "setSize" that doesn't work for me.

Maybe I have to make a second panel or something like that, I hope you can help me solving this issue.

I guess an Image says more than 1,000 words, so:

This is what I get and have and what I want to have

[image]

So in plain english, all I want to know is how to render table and add button at the bottom after rendered table (but I don't want buttons to have all the frame width, I want them away from table, not together as I have them and with the possibility to change their size and position).

Comment: Why in the name of Hades did someone down-vote this question??

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't know it was like 8-12 months ago, someone just downvoted it and I was like... why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
private void createUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JTable table = new JTable(10, 4);

        JPanel btnPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel topBtnPnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        JPanel bottombtnPnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        topBtnPnl.add(new JButton("Select All"));
        bottombtnPnl.add(new JButton("Cancel"));
        bottombtnPnl.add(new JButton("Add Selected"));

        btnPnl.add(topBtnPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnPnl.add(bottombtnPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);



        frame.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btnPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setTitle("JTable Example.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: +1 for leveraging the layout; I've suggested how to update the model [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17230777/230513).

Answer (score 2):

[`CheckABunch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513) is an example that shows how to update the `TableModel` based on the current selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at `GridLayout`.

In short I've made some changes to your class, and I've got this:

- First group all `JButtons` into a `JPanel`, which have a `GridLayout` inside
- Also, your JFrame container must have a `BorderLayout`
- So you need add each button to the auxiliary pane and at the end add both `JPanels` to the frame.

Here's the code:

```
//Another import sentences
import java.awt.GridLayout;

class kanji{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // More code goes here
        JPanel allowedOperations = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // More code goes here

        // All buttons are grouped here
        allowedOperations.add(new JButton()); // Here's a trick 
        allowedOperations.add(agreg);
        allowedOperations.add(new JButton("Save selected"));
        allowedOperations.add(new JButton("Cancel"));

        // Add the pane object to the frame
        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // And finally add the allowedOperations object to the frame
        frame.add(allowedOperations, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        // More code goes here
} //End class
```

I've just posted the modifications, so you need to group the whole class.

I know it isn't the best approach, but you can improve your code from here. Also note you can create your buttons before added to the `allowedOperations` pane, as the `agreg` button

Comment: `JTable` will scale better as the model grows.