# How to add JCheckBox dynamically to each row retrieved from MySQL database to JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have data from the database on my `JTable`. I want to add checkboxes to each row dynamically from the database. I will later use these checkboxes to delete rows checked  from the database. I know how to delete from the database, but how to add checkboxes from the database? Any one done this before please help. I am a Java enthusiast trying to learn it. A sample code could help me understand how to do this.

Code below is for updating my `JTable`:

```
public void UpdateTable() {

    try {

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
                + "employee_certificate", "root", "");

        String sql = "SELECT certificate.Number, staff.Emp_Id, staff.Emp_Name, "
                + "staff.Department,  certificate.Cert_Code, certificate.Cert_Name,\n"
                + "certificate.Vendor, certificate.Date_Taken, "
                + "certificate.Expiry_Date FROM staff LEFT JOIN certificate"
                + " ON staff.Emp_Id=certificate.Emp_Id ORDER BY staff.Emp_Name\n";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not set the table so multiple rows can be selected, and have a separate (outside the table) button to `Delete Selected Rows`?

Comment: I don't want the user  to have hard time in trying to remember something like ctrl+a or ctrl+c .i just want them to use  checkboxes that are more user friendly to them

Comment: I completely disagree. But hey, good luck with it.

Comment: In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225988/how-to-add-jbutton-after-a-jtable) I had done something similar (it didn't came from a database but you can change the data object to your result set of your select query)

Comment: Myself, I'd create my own table model from the database data, and add a column of Booleans to the data.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels please elaborate

Comment: Wannabe: have a look at the Oracle tutorial on JTables, especially the model section, and then create your own table model, not using DbUtils.

Comment: @WannabeJavaGeek *please elaborate* Please elaborate a [mcve] for us to help you, as is, this question cannot have more help than the link and recommendation comments we're giving you

Comment: Start with this complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513), I made the changes below to get the following result. In particular,

- `Row` is given an attribute `Boolean checked`, replacing `String name`.
- The default [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) uses a check box when `getColumnClass()` returns `Boolean.class` for `Row.checked`.
- In the corresponding JDBC and SQL, the `checked` attribute is of type `boolean`.

[image]

```
$ diff Original.java WorkerTest.java 
48c48
<         String name;
---
>         Boolean checked;
91c91
<                     return row.name;
---
>                     return row.checked;
105a106,116
>         @Override
>         public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colIndex) {
>             switch (colIndex) {
>                 case 0:
>                     return Integer.class;
>                 case 1:
>                     return Boolean.class;
>             }
>             return null;
>         }
> 
114c125
<                         r.name = rs.getString(2);
---
>                         r.checked = rs.getBoolean(2);
138c149
<             st.execute("create table city(id integer, name varchar2)");
---
>             st.execute("create table city(id integer, checked boolean)");
143,144c154
<                 ps.setString(2, (char) ('A' + r.nextInt(26))
<                     + String.valueOf(r.nextInt(1_000_000)));
---
>                 ps.setBoolean(2, Boolean.valueOf(r.nextBoolean()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `DBUtils` returns a complete `TableModel`.

The easiest way is to NOT use `DBUtils` and to load the data from the `ResultSet` into the `TableModel` yourself.

The code is not difficult and you can use the `Table From Database Example` found in [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) as the starting point.

The code just loads the data from the ResultSet into Vectors, so you can then manually add another column to contain Boolean data.

The (two) changes to the code would be something like:

```
//  Get column names

for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
{
    columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
}

columnName.addElement( "Check Mark" ); // added

//  Get row data

while (rs.next())
{
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }

    row.addElement( Boolean.FALSE ); // added
    data.addElement( row );
}
```