# how to get value from ticked jcheckbox in a row from jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table with 3 column and dynamic row based from database value and a jcheckbox in last column based on this code :

```
  TableColumn tcolumn = tabel.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
     tcolumn.setCellRenderer(tabel.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
       tcolumn.setCellEditor(tabel.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
```

example of my table:

```
============================================
val 1 || val 2 || val 3 (checkbox) ||
============================================

from FB || from DB || checkbox           ||

from DB || from DB || checkbox           ||

===========================================
```

My question is simple, how can I get all of the value 1 from the ticked checkbox in column 2 (value 3)?

I tried many simple code but still got an error.

this is my code:

```
for (int row =0; row <= tabel.getSelectedRowCount(); row++) {
  Boolean b = ((Boolean) tblModel.getValueAt(row, 2));
     if (b.booleanValue()) {
       System.out.print(tblModel.getValueAt(row, 0)+" || ");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show what have you tried.

Comment: I can't really explain your problem, question is - can you?

Comment: Looks like you already had those values in your `String[] fieldData`, now what do you need?

Comment: if i marked 1st row, it get the value but the output show error.
i want to, example :

if i marked first row, third row, and 5th row, it get value from their colomn 0. ==> 1011501100,1011501102,1011501104. but it still get error. is my logic in that code wrong ?

Comment: i got error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException and the 3rd column absolutelly a boolean value, but it nothing to do/not linking to database, it just a condition, if i ticked, then my logic are run (System.out.print(tblModel.getValueAt(row, 0)+" || ");)

Comment: You still haven't posted a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). That is how you improve a question. That is you show a simple program with a table a button and the code you execute when you click the button. Then maybe we can help explain why your looping logic isn't working.

Comment: @user2512451: As you have complied with Hovercraft's [request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17264828/230513), I'll hazard a [guess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17265891/230513).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what error you get or where you get it; I suspect an error casting to `Boolean`. As general guidance, the [default renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for `Boolean.class` is a `JCheckbox`; you shouldn't have to set it explicitly. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513), ensure that you observe the following principles for your cast to succeed:

- Insert values of type `Boolean.class` in your `TableModel`.
- Return `Boolean.class` from `getColumnClass()` for the relevant column.
- Return the desired value from `isCellEditable()`.

Comment: @Volatil3: Some examples are seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20DefaultTableModel%20Boolean.class).