# Selecting all items in a list

Tags: java, swing, list

I'm working on `Java Swing List` and I wanna select all its values or items with the use of `jCheckBox`. I tried searching some answer on google and I could hardly find any.

I hope I can get answers from here.

Thanks.

EDIT:

In my swing list, I have these items for example:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

and I have a checkbox label as '`Select All`'.

So what I want is when my checkbox is selected/checked, All the items in the swing list will be selected at once.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: So far, I haven't tried any.

Comment: hint: skim the api doc on how to select a range of items, then extrapolate to all ...

Comment: Added some more details, please check.

Comment: Something like `JList#getSelectionModel#setSelectionInterval`?

Comment: Thanks men, that's the solution. Cant believe I missed it. darn

Comment: Several alternatives are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17951886/230513).

Comment: *"and I wanna select all its values.."*  Do you want to spell expressions like 'want to' properly, or should I ignore you?

Answer (score 0):

You want JList's

" void  setSelectedIndices(int[] indices) 
          Changes the selection to be the set of indices specified by the given array."

method. Don't forget to activate the property that allows multiselect  Also remember to cancel stuff when the box is unchecked!

good luck

Comment: ehhh ... no, wrong method (you don't want to to create an array containing all indices ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a setter and getter for list size. The getter will be the end point of setSelectionInterval(start, end);

`JList list = new JList();`
`private void insertItem(){`
`DefaultListModel<String> list_model = new DefaultListModel<String>();`
`String listData[] = {"Fish", "Pork", "Chicken", "Curry"};`
`for(int i = 0; i < listData.length; i++)`
`list_model.addElement(listData[i]);`
`list.setModel(list_model);`
`setListSize(list.size());`
`}`

`foodCb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {`
`@Override`
`public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {`
`if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)`
`list.setSelectionInterval(0, getListSize());`
`else`
`list.clearSelection();`
`}`
`});`

`int list_size = 0;`
`private void setListSize(int size)`  `{ list_size = size; }`

`private void getListSize() { return list_size; }`