# How to add JCheckBox beside a String in JList and allows it to select and open multiple files stored in a folder without the use of ctrl key?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcheckbox

I am still quite new to Netbeans interface but I would like to ask for help with some coding. My intention is to make a GUI where it would be populated with the files that are stored in the specified directory which I have succeeded.

However, now I wish to include check box beside the file name that are displayed in the checklist. So when user checked the check the check box or check boxes, it can open the files that are stored in the folder and displayed on the `JList`.

How could I allow user to select and open multiple files by checking the checkboxs without using the ctrl keys?

Below is my code.

```
   public status() {
        initComponents();

          DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
         File o = new File("c:/Users/zikai/Desktop/test");

         File[] yourFileList = o.listFiles();

         jList1.setCellRenderer(new CheckboxListCellRenderer());
        for(File f : yourFileList) {
            model1.addElement(/*ch[i]*/ f.getName());

        }
        jList1.setModel(model1);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("cancel");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("okay");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jList1.setToolTipText("");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(262, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 371, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 63, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    public class CheckboxListCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        setComponentOrientation(list.getComponentOrientation());
        setFont(list.getFont());
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
        setSelected(isSelected);
        setEnabled(list.isEnabled());

        setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());  

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: You can't add `JCheckBox` to `JList` instean you need to use one column `JTable`. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17952140/2894369).

Comment: The difference between mine and his is his items in the JList are fixed or predefined. But mine have to do a loop in the folder then return the list of files.

Comment: It haven't  difference. You need to create a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with `JCheckBox` column and then dynamically populate it.