# How to display an ArrayList in a JPanel

Tags: arraylist, jpanel

How can I get a JList to show in a JPenel. For example I'd like to have the following groups of items displayed in a JPanel, with each group showing on it's own column, with a new group being dropped into a new line, like how Google lists search results.

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ReaderImpl {
    JPanel paneTo = new JPanel();

    List<String> text() {
        List<String> lovely = new ArrayList<String>(4);
            lovely.add("Tall, Short, Average");         // line 1
            lovely.add("mangoes, apples, Bananas");     // line 2
            lovely.add("12, 33");  
        return lovely;
    }

    // How do I add the lovely ArrayList to paneTo
}
```

Comment: You want to use a JListBox and set the listModel to your data.

Comment: What is `Reader`? Where do columns come into this; you seem to want the different strings put into their own rows.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. No more "extends Reader" now. Hope you can help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JList` renderer can draw a checkbox, but `JList` **does not** support a cell editor. Instead, consider a one-column `JTable.`

Check out this [link here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526779/multiple-row-selection-in-jtable/4528604#4528604)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @olicvermuchai Not a problem. I would appreciate if the answer helped you, can you upvote or accept the answer and close the question. Thanks

Comment: I will a bit later. can't upvote you right now: just joined StackOverflow and my points aren't high enough.