# How to change or find column type in JTable

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable

I want to insert `JCheckBox` in every row in `JTable` so I try to change my first column type. When I try this code, I get "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean" error.

```
 DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
             @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {  
                    switch (column) {  
                        case 0:
                            return Boolean.class;
                        case 1:  
                            return String.class;
                        case 2:  
                            return String.class;
                        case 3:  
                            return String.class; 
                        default:
                            return   String.class;
                    }  
           } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be certain to add values of type `Boolean.class` to your `TableModel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513). See also [*Creating a Table Model*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for a typical implementation.

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
}
```

Addendum: *I changed row value as* `true`.

There are several ways to ensure that the model contains a value of type `Boolean.class`:

- `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FLASE`, constants defined in [`java.lang.Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html).
- `Boolean.valueOf(boolean b)`, where `b` may be a value or expression yielding `boolean`.
- `true` or `false`, [literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.3) that are [autoboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) since Java 1.5.

As @kleopatra notes, the simple tutorial implementation fails to meet two essential critera:

- Guard against `null` values.
- Return the same value for the lifetime of the model.

Comment: I changed row value as true in resultment statement. it works too.

Comment: funny how subtly incorrect solutions tend to spread at times ;-) Copying my  recent comment to @Reimnus' answer in a similar question: a) asking the value for its class should at least be guarded against null b) asking the value for its class may subtly violate TableModel's contract: the class must be the same for the lifetime of the model, which isn't guaranteed if the the value is changed

Comment: @Alify am I interpreting your comment correctly when assuming that the _content_ of the first column bad not been booleans? So your error was elsewhere, your original approach (regarding column class) was and is correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
static String[] columnNames={"Name","Surname","Boolean"};
static Object[][] data={ {null,null,null };
JTable table=new JTable(data,columnNames);


public static void RESULTS(){
try{
rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
Object[] row=new Object[2];
 DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
             @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {  
                    switch (column) {  
                        case 2: return Boolean.class;
                        default: return   String.class;
                                     }  
            }        
};
table.setModel(model);
model.setColumnIdentifiers(columNames);
while (rs.next()){
            for (int v=1;v<3;v++){
                    if(v==2){ row[2]=false; // or true..

                             } 
                    else{ row[v-1]=rs.getObject(v); }     
            }
            model.addRow(row);            
}//while
rs.close();
 }//try
 catch (SQLException e) { System.out.println(e); }           
 }
```

I did that, it works