# Get all selected index of Checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am a beginner to Java Swing. I have a table with 3 columns. The first column has only check boxes.  I wanted to get the index of all the selected items of the check box and store it in an `ArrayList`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How i can i accomplish this? - by 1. reading Oracle tutorial HOw to use Tables 2. post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Are you talking about a JTable?

Comment: @mKorbel..what is sscce?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).

Comment: Yes i am using JTable

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this,

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SwingCheckBoxDemo.htm

If you want to return all selected items, you can use List or Set for this.

Post the code what you have. I may assist...

Comment: Please the cite the original [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox); the knock-off is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

As you use a JTable you are using a TableCellRenderer for the "checkbox column". As long you add check boxes to column 1 you "know" in which row the checkbox is created. As you know the row(=index) you can register an action to collect together the checked boxes index.

(from scratch)

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, final int row, int column) {
    if (column != 1) {
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
    JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();
    cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            list.add(row); // whatever list is ...
        }

    });
    return cb;
}
```

}