# Mulitiple delete record from jtable through id which is link to database

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

My question: How to allow user to perform multiple delete  from jtable through button.The table is
linked to my database.I have created a table model in another class and link to my SalesReceiptTable.
I am able to delete one row from both the db and table when the user click the delete button.
Should i do looping for the rowSelected ??

```
    //Button to perform delete
    JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
btnDelete.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int rowSelected=SalesReceiptTable.getSelectedRow();
if(rowSelected>=0)
{
String id = SalesReceiptTable.getValueAt(rowSelected, 7).toString();
SalesReceipt1 e1=new SalesReceipt1(Integer.parseInt(id));
    e1.deleteSalesReceipt();
ArrayList<SalesReceipt1> result= SalesReceipt1.retrieveAllSalesReceipt();
SalesReceiptTableModel model= new SalesReceiptTableModel(result);
SalesReceiptTable.setModel(model);
    }
else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No record selected","Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    //My sql statement in my entity class
    public boolean deleteSalesReceipt(){
boolean success = false;
DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery; 
db.getConnection();
    dbQuery = "DELETE FROM SalesReceipt WHERE salesReceiptId ='" + salesReceiptId +"'"; 
    if (db.updateRequest(dbQuery) == 1){
success = true;
                               }
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted and where you're having problems?

Answer (score 2):

Several approaches are possible:

- Specify `ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` in the table's `setSelectionMode()` method, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), and examine the result returned by `getSelectedRows()`.
- Add a column of check boxes, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513), and enable the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button only when any are selected.

In all cases,

- Convert between view and model row indices, as discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).
- Consider supporting *undo* using a `List<Row>` to cache rows deleted from the model but not yet deleted from the database.