# jtable checkbox with action binding

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

hi my java swing project have a table with last column is boolean values..i changed it into chceckbox.but i need to bind event on it and know if it is check or not..!!

Below Code works it is showing checkbox

```
retunTable=new JTable(model){
                  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    /*@Override
                    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
                    }*/
                    @Override
                    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                        switch (column) {
                            case 0:
                                return Object.class;
                            case 1:
                                return Object.class;
                            case 2:
                                return Object.class;
                            case 3:
                                return Object.class;
                            default:
                                return Boolean.class;
                        }
                    }
            };
```

i dont know where to put addActionListener..!!

Help needed..!!

Answer (score 5):

> i dont know where to put addActionListener..!!

- `TableCellEditort/Renderer`  isn't real `JComponent`
- override `setValueAt` in `XxxTableModel`
- I woudln't suggest to use custom `TableCellEditort/Renderer` for this job
- override `getColumnClass` in `XxxTableModel` instead for subclassing `JTable`

Comment: A related example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).