# How to fetch checked values from check boxes in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jcheckbox

I have JTable with name 'tableEarnings' it consist of 3 columns:

- check
- Earnings
- Description
  and  a
- jButton

Every cell in 'check' column have a checkbox. I need to fetch checked values of 'Earnings' and 'Description' cell  from `JTable` and store it to a database when I click `jButton`
please help me

This my code for button listener:

```
private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //System.out.println("table"+tableEarnings.getModel().getRowCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < tableEarnings.getModel().getRowCount()+1; i++) {    
        if ((Boolean) tableEarnings.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0)) {
           System.out.println("Value" + tableEarnings.getValueAt(i, 1));
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use getValueAt to fetch data

Comment: how can i traverse the checked values?

Comment: @jiplin if you have tried something plz post it

Comment: @Jipin Gopi 1. how can i traverse the checked values? - use getValueAt to fetch data, 2. event from getValueAt, output to database should be redirected to the SwingWorker, 3. boolean valur stored in model representing JChechBox in JTable, 4. everything about JTable in official Oracle tutorial, incl. working code examples

Comment: Examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).

Answer (score 3):

There are three simple mistakes in your loop iterating over the table model:

1. Top bound for `i` variable should be row count - 1. Otherwise you will probably get an exception (i.e.: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your table model is `DefaultTableModel`)
2. If you find a `true` boolean value then don't `break` the loop. By doing this you lose all  rows further than `i` index.
3. You are printing the value calling `getValueAt()` directly on the table (view) not the model. This might not retrieve the correct value if your table is sorted or columns were reordered. Always keep consistency. In this case you should work with the model.

For example:

```
private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    TableModel model = tableEarnings.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount() - 1; i++) {    
        if ((Boolean) model.getValueAt(i, 0)) {
           System.out.println("Value" + model.getValueAt(i, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to print the values.

If everything goes well you have the basis now to insert the rows in your database. But be aware that database calls are time consuming tasks and may block the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) causing the GUI become unresponsive. The EDT is a single and special thread where Swing components creation and update take place. To avoid block this thread consider use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform database calls in a background thread and update Swing components in the EDT. See more in [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) lesson.

Comment: Thanks Dic .But again it shows an exception when checking the second index

Comment: Could you please edit your question including the exception? @JipinGopi