# Checkbox column editing on JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, jcheckbox

I have a `JTable` in which one column is a checkbox. I want to let the user edit the checkbox by mouse drag: if they clicked one checkbox and drag mouse into other checkbox, they will get the same result with the first checkbox clicked.

Comment: If you want to use mouse hover to edit checkbox, then why you are using drag option? because hovering over the rows makes you select or deselect the check boxes. Will you please elaborate more on requirement.

Comment: sorry, i means mouse hover, when you clicked one checkbox and still press mouse button then move into other checkBox they will be affected

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to specify `ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` for the table's selection model, as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection). Click and drag to select contiguous rows, or add the <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd> modifiers to select disparate rows. In a suitable `Action`, update the `TableModel` to reflect the selection, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513). The `JTable` will update itself in response.

[image]

Comment: thank you,but I want to edit it without press ctrl or shift

Comment: @Ives: You can select contiguous rows with click and drag; only multiple interval selection requires modifier keys.

Comment: yes, I use MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION, but I disabled rows select by drag, because I have drag and drop too,it will confused user , so if want MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION work ,you have to press ctrl or shift

Comment: You might need a custom `ListSelectionModel`.